# Reading & writing Files - Java empty spaces

Tags: java, string, file-io, filewriter, replaceall

I want to read from a file and write to a file. The input file is as follows

```
<ORLANDO>   <0%>
    As I remember, Adam, it was upon this fashion bequeathed me by will but poor a thousand crowns, and, as thou sayest,
<ORLANDO>

"A s   I   r e m e m b e r    A d a m    i t   w a s   u p o n   t h i s   f a s h i o n   b e q u e a t h e d   m e   b y   w i l l   b u t   p o o r   a   t h o u s a n d   c r o w n s    a n d    a s   t h o u   s a y e s t    c h a r g e d   m y   b r o t h e r   o n  ..."
```

I have written a java program to remove lines with tags and also replace any punctuation with spaces. But each letter that is written out has a space in between and also in between lines lots of blank lines are present. How to remove them? . Please help.

```
String line=null;
    try {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader( new FileReader("filename"));
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("filename"));
    try {
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            {

                if(!line.contains("<"))
                {
                    line=(line.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}",""));

                    writer.println(line);
                    writer.flush();


                 }
            }
}
```

Comment: ran the code and could not repeat your problem. What's the encoding of your input file?

Comment: Code worked fine for me .. All I did was remove that extra `try`  you have .. Check the encoding issues .

Answer (score 5):

When you open a file with PrintWriter by default it truncates the file.  You can set it to append instead, but either way you cannot rewrite a file you are reading from this way.

Instead you should create a new file and write to that.  When you have finished you can delete the original and rename the copy (or delete the copy if it is exactly the same)

> But each letter that is written out has a space in between and also in between lines lots of blank lines are present.

This would happen for you wrote UTF-16 but read it as ASCII or UTF-8.  The way to avoid this is to not use UTF-16 which is not the default.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("filename"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
     PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("filename.tmp"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
    for(String line; (line = br.readLine())!=null;) {
        pw.println(line.replaceAll("<[^>]+>", ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: I assumed  different files would have been used for reading and writing . +1 for the insight you had .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening the written file with the correct encoding. It looks like you write UTF-8 and open it with ASCII or any ISO-8859 encoding.

Comment: More likely the other way around - if the original file was UTF-16 and you are reading it as Windows-1252 then you'd get a nul between each real character.